# Graded Vector Spaces (definition)

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory, operads

I am studying Algebraic Operads with the book Algebraic Operads, by Jean-Louis Loday and Bruno Vallette and I'm having a little problem with the definition of graded vector space. My advisor and I disagree on the definition. The book defines it this way:
[image]

my advisor thinks it is equivalent to saying that $V = \bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} V_n$. I believe that they are different. In nLab ([Graded Vector Spaces](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/graded+vector+space)) I found the following definition
[image]

which strengthens my argument.
Finally, who is correct? Can anyone suggest me any other reference about graded vector spaces?

Comment: What does your advisor mean by $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}V_n$? At the moment, it just seems you are disagreeing on notation (I'm guessing you would write $\oplus_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}V_n$).

Comment: Sorry, I typed wrong. I corrected now.

Comment: I don't understand what notation you are proposing to use for a graded vector space. The one in the first screenshot and the one proposed by your advisor denote the same thing as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two different categories:

- The category $\mathsf{gVec}$ where objects are vector spaces $V$ equipped with a decomposition $V \cong \bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} V_n$, and morphisms are linear maps respecting the decomposition;
- The category $\mathsf{Vec}^\mathbb{Z}$ of families of vector spaces $\{ V_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ and morphisms $f : \{V_n\} \to \{W_n\}$ are families of linear maps $\{f_n : V_n \to W_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$.

These two categories are equivalent; you can construct an explicit equivalence $\mathsf{Vec}^\mathbb{Z} \to \mathsf{gVec}$ given by $\{V_n\} \mapsto V_\bullet = \bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} V_n$. So it makes no difference to consider graded vector spaces from the first point of view or from the second point of view.